# ADFS 2.1 Changes (and LDS)

Tags: adlds, adfs2.1

I have not had any luck finding a consolidated view of changes from ADFS 2.0 to 2.1. Is there such a resource out there? I'm interested in new features.

Also, I'm looking specifically if AD/LDS can be used as an IdP for ADFS 2.1. I believe this was possible in ADFS 1.0, then not in ADFS 2.0, and I'm hoping (though against hope, I think) that it's back in ADFS 2.1.

Thanks for any help on either of these two questions.

Answer (score 0):

Refer: [Guidelines for Migrating an Application Built Using WIF 3.5 to WIF 4.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj157089.aspx).

That's the basic difference.

In ADFS 2.1, ADFS and WIF are built-in - no need for seperate downloads.

For completeness, in R2, [Extending device support in Active Directory](http://blogs.technet.com/b/ad/archive/2013/07/10/extending-device-support-in-active-directory.aspx).

No - no change to LDS.